# <g:checkBox> click calling a controller function

Tags: grails, gsp

When the user clicks on the checkbox, I want to call a controller function and pass the current status of checkbox, whether it's checked or not.

I know how to do this using jQuery but I want to do this from the checkBox itself.

```
<g:checkBox id="customer_checkbox" name="customer_checkbox" value="${checked}" />
```

Controller function to be called:

```
class updateController {
   def updateIndex () {
      // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the page to refresh when the user clicks the checkbox, i.e. does it need to be AJAX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U need to use remoteFunction from grails taglib. This tag generate for u ajax function:

```
<select from="[1,2,3,4,5]" onchange="${remoteFunction(action: 'updateIndex', controller:'update',options: '[asynchronous: true]'}" />
```

For more information go to [docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html)

Answer (score 1):

The checkbox would be a part of the form. Use javascript to invoke the action.

```
<g:form name="formName" controller="updateController" action="updateIndex">
    <!-- Other form elements -->
    <g:checkBox id="customer_checkbox" name="customer_checkbox" value="${checked}" onChange="document.getElementById('formName').submit();"/>
</g:form>
```